# Как удалить второй элемент из списка?

Tags: c

Кажется загвоздка в том, чтобы в функции "Udal" после удаления второго элемента, указатель первого элемента должен указывать на начало третьего. 
Честно, это задача из лабораторной работы. Мне сейчас особенно, нужен совет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAXDL 9

int h = 0;

struct EL_SP {
    char id[MAXDL];
    struct EL_SP *sled;
};

void Vkl(struct EL_SP **p, char t_id[])
{
    struct EL_SP *pt, *k, *j;
    pt = (struct EL_SP *) malloc(sizeof(struct EL_SP));
    strcpy(pt->id, t_id);
    if (*p == NULL || strcmp(pt->id, (*p)->id) < 0) {
        pt->sled = *p;
        *p = pt;
    } else {
        k = *p;
        while (k != NULL && strcmp(pt->id, k->id) >= 0) {
            j = k;
            k = k->sled;
        }
        j->sled = pt;
        pt->sled = k;
    }
}

// функция для удаления и вывода результата после комментария avp:

  void Udal(struct EL_SP *p)
{ 
    struct EL_SP *next;
    int m;
     for( next=p, m=0; next!=NULL; next=next->sled)
      {
        m++;
    if (m==2)
         free (next);
break;
     }

 }

   void PechSp(struct EL_SP *p)
    {
        struct EL_SP *i;
        printf("n Rezultat:n");
        for (i = p; i != NULL; i = i->sled)
            puts(i->id);
    }

void main()
{
    struct EL_SP *p;
    unsigned n;
    unsigned i;
    char t_id[MAXDL];

    printf("n vvedite chislo identificatorovn n=");
    scanf("%u", &n);
    getchar();
    p = NULL;
    printf("vvedite identificatori");
    printf("(posle kagdogo najimayte klavishu <ENTER>) n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        gets(t_id);
        Vkl(&p, t_id);
    }
  Udal(p);   //здесь её вызываю
    PechSp(p);
    printf("nn Dlya zaversheniya najmite lybuyu klavishun");
    getch();
}
```

Программа компилируется без ошибок, но после ввода идентификаторов вылетает.

Comment: Страуструп пошел себя наказывать... =) 
Перебирай список, смотри на индекс, если тот что надо - удаляй значение

Comment: В первом элементе заменить sled на sled из второго. Второй удалить. Только смотрите внимательно, что 1-ый и 2-ой существуют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@AlexC](/users/7428/alexc), Вы путаете работу с указателями в массивах и связных списках (это как у Вас. struct EL_SP ссылается на другой struct EL_SP по адресу в поле sled).

Посмотрите материалы по связным спискам еще раз и измените логику построения и обхода списка.

Советую связать со списком 2 указателя - head (на первый в списке) и tail (на последний). Например можно определить список так:

```
struct list {
    struct EL_SP *head, *tail;
    int    list_length;
};
```

При инициализации (создании пустого списка) сделайте head = tail = NULL.

Удачи.

Comment: @avp, а если вдруг будет добавлен элемент в конец списка, тогда нужно будет исправлять все tail?

Comment: @insolor, видимо я что-то непонятно написал в ответе. Это был комментарий и я подробно не ссылался на структуры данных из вопроса.

Для каждого списка struct list  своя (**один экземпляр на список**). Один head, один tail.
head указывает на первую struct EL_SP, указатель sled (**в ней**) на следующую struct EL_SP и т.д. tail из struct list адоесует последнюю struct EL_SP в списке. sled в ней NULL.

IMHO очевидно.

Comment: @avp, все, понял. Просто не вчитался в ответ.